# How to convert json to object without any model or mapper in c#

Tags: c#

How to convert json to object in c#? Below is sample of json and some time it can be complex json. I don't want to use any model. and not using any mapper. Please suggest something-

```
{'firstName':'Ram','country':'India','email':'test@test.com'}
```

Json will be different every time like-

```
{'firstName':'Ram','lastName':'tho','country':'India','email':'test@test.com'}

{'firstName':'Ram','country':'India','state':'MP','city':'Bhp'}
```

Sample code will be appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: Please explain "*I don't want to use any model.*" also "*. and not using any mapper*"

Comment: I'd still recommend creating a model object with the fields you will use. You don't have to map all of them, and any missing fields would just end up null.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I want to create a method which accepts object not any model class. If there is any change I don't want to change model class and other. I will get a json, I need to convert json data to key value pair like(from above example- "firstName":"Ram", 'country':'India') and so on..

Comment: This seems like an X/Y problem, your json schema seems to be a subset of one another, and an actual type with optional fields. Anyway if you have no nested objects. just deserialize to a Dictionary<string,string> and be done with it

Answer (score 0):

You can resort to using "json path" or property path notation if you construct a `JObject` from [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) based on that data.

Just don't complain about performance if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I work with JSON and Web-based APIs regularly and will never use anything else than Newtonsoft in C# to handle JSON conversions, it's literally the best possible way to do anything with JSON in C# and without any headaches, it's the most popular C# NuGet package in the world with almost 1 billion downloads, works in ALL .NET versions basically.

Here's one of the simplest examples

```
string json_string = @"{
                  Firstname: ""Jane"",
                  Lastname: ""Doe"",
                  Age: 36,
                  IsEmployed: true,
                  IsMarried: true,
                  Children: 4
              }";
              
var person = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_string);

Console.WriteLine(person.Forename);
Console.WriteLine(person.Lastname);
Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
Console.WriteLine(person.IsEmployed);
Console.WriteLine(person.IsMarried);
Console.WriteLine(person.Children);
```

It generates objects on the fly, no matter the structure! Other solutions don't work in all .NET versions.

I wrote a simple, easy-to-follow article here https://turmanauli.medium.com/a-complete-guide-for-serializing-json-to-dynamic-objects-on-the-fly-in-c-7ab4799f648d
about how to install and use Newtonsoft via NuGet Package Manager in your Visual Studio project.